# We know $ \lim_{b \to 1}f_b(n)=n$ when $f_b(n)={b^n -1\over b-1}$ . How can we derive the limit for the inverse of $f_b(x)$?

Tags: calculus

For the $q$-analogue of the power-function
$  \qquad \qquad \displaystyle  [n]_b = f_b(n)={b^n -1\over b-1}$

it is not too difficult to show why

$ \qquad \qquad \displaystyle \lim_{b \to 1} [n]_b = f_b(n)=n$

I tried (originally for programming purposes) to do the same derivation for the inverse of $f_b(x)$ (for the functional inverse, not for the reciprocal!)

$ \qquad \qquad \displaystyle x = {b^y-1\over b-1} \\ 
 \qquad \qquad   b^y-1=x(b-1) \\
 \qquad \qquad   y = \log_b(x(b-1)+1) = {\log(x(b-1)+1)\over \log(b)}$.

but I don't see it at the moment.

How can I write down the derivation for that expression in the limit as $b \to 1$?

Comment: What's wrong with setting b=1 in the last line from what follows log_b(1)=y, so y=0?

Comment: @Hendrik: We get $\log(0)$ in the denominator (I just included that expression in that formula t make it explicite)

Comment: Oh, my fault. Was just thinking that anything to the zeroth power is 1, but for base 1 it can be any number, so we don't get any further. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat faster is just applying applying l'Hospital  $$
  \lim_{b\to 1} \log_b(x(b-1)+1) = \lim_{b\to 1} \frac{\ln (x(b-1)+1)}{\ln b}
  = \lim_{b\to 1} \frac{\frac{x}{x(b-1)+1}}{\frac{1}{b}}
 = \lim_{b\to 1} \frac{xb}{x(b-1)+1} = x 
$$

Comment: @GottfriedHelms One of us is confused. Let's assume it's not me for a second, then if $h(x) = f(x)/g(x) = 1/x$, it follows that $f(x) = 1$ and $g(x) = x$, so $f'(x)/g'(x) = 0/1$. Of course, $(f(x)/g(x))' = (0x - 1)/x^2 = -1/x^2$, but that's not the issue here...

Comment: Urrgh - it seems I had my mind elsewhere in my comments. They were based on a thinking on a completely wrong path, just deleted them all. Sorry for inconvenience. I'll look at it after a break having a coffee...  ;-)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms No worries! Enjoy your coffee ;-)

Comment: Well, I'd mixed Lhospital and L'Eibniz... Knot in the mind... So, thanks for your answer and working this out.

Comment: "Accepted" because it did "open-the-mind". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ah, that was not so difficult, sorry for bothering the community...
$$ \begin{eqnarray} y& =& { \log(x(b-1)+1)\over \log(b)} \\
  y &=& { \log(1+x(e^c-1))\over \log(e^c)} & \text { //  writing $b$ as } e^c\\
  y &=& { x(e^c-1)-(x(e^c-1))^2/2+ ....\over c} & \text { //  expanding $log$ into mercator series } \\
  y &=& { x(c+c^2/2!+...)-x^2(c +c^2/2!+...)^2/2+ ....\over c} & \text { // expanding  } e^c-1 \\
  y &=&  x(1+c/2!+...)-x^2c( ...)/2+ .... & \text { // cancelling  } c \\
 \end{eqnarray} $$
then
$ \qquad \qquad \displaystyle\begin{eqnarray}
  \lim_{c \to 0} y &=& x & \qquad \qquad \text { // letting   } c \to 0 
 \end{eqnarray}
$